# How to change the color of pop-up windows in an application flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tell me, I have a Share popup menu in white color. I need to change the color, how do I do it? There is no option in the share_plus package itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't do. That piece of widget is not Flutter related, it's the device itself. Outside the scope of flutter.

Comment: Understood, thank you very much for your help, then I will not try to change the color)